# Why is appendTo only working once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am write some validation code.

The structure of the objects referenced in the code below looks like this roughly

```
invalidFields = { 'fieldOne' : true, 'fieldTwo' : true }
messages = { 'fieldOne' : 'Message' , 'fieldTwo' : 'MessageTwo' }
```

`invalidFields` is an object containing the `name='fieldName'` names for various `input` tags. The following code should add the error `errorList`

```
var errorList = jQuery("<ul class='errorList'></ul>");
var sb = jQuery('div#statusBar');

var templateErrorLi = jQuery('<li></li>' );
var invalidFieldsLength = // some logic which I forget (editing my question from a bus)


if (invalidFieldsLength > 0) {
    sb.show()
    errorList.appendTo(sb);
}

else {
    sb.hide()
    sb.detach()
}

for (var key in invalidFields) {

    if (invalidFields.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var invalid = form.find('[name="' + key + '"]');
        invalid.addClass('error');
        templateErrorLi.clone().text(messages[key]).appendTo(errorList);
    }
}
```

The HTML that this references is simply an empty DIV.

```
<div id='statusBar'></div>
```

For some reason this works once but only once. The second item in the invalidFields object doesn't append, even though that for loop definitely iterated across it. If anyone can tell me why this doesn't work it would be much appreciated :) Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a snippet and explain?

Comment: Why don't you use Ramda or Lodash for object iteration?

Comment: @PraveenKumar sorry didn't explain the problem clearly enough. Edited.

Comment: You should use `for (var key of Object.keys(invalidFields))` instead.

Comment: @TaoP.R. Apologies I didn't explain the problem; the loop works... See my edit

Comment: @DejanToteff apologies I didn't explain the problem fully. The problem is not the loop; that works fine. See edit.

Comment: Hmmm, let me remove my answer. I think I didn't get it right.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m43wp6ph/. the loop works here and both the keys are bind to UL. I suppose you get JS error in second iteration of loop. 'invalid' is null. please share the html too.

Comment: @Moniecorleone I've just edited it as best I can from memory. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, I have realized what the problem is;

```
 var errorList = jQuery("<ul class='errorList'></ul>");
```

The above code is run inside the context of the function, which means that it is created brand new each time. Although there are still a few bugs to contend with, the following solved my original problem:

```
if ( jQuery('#statusBar .errorList').length == 0 ) {
    errorList = jQuery("<ul class='errorList'></ul>");
}

else {
    errorList = jQuery('#statusBar .errorList');
}
```